# Deleting Zip Entry from Zip archive using Minizip API

Tags: zip, unzip

I am using Minizip API to zip and unzip file to and from my archive. I have a requirement  to delete the zip entry from the zip as soon as i extract it.

if the zip archive has multiple zip entries , i am able to delete a particular zip entry soon as i extract it and then able to zip archive  with the remaining zip entries. i am able to achieve this using a temp zip .

But when i have a single file inside the zip archive, i am only able to delete the zip after complete extraction....Can there be a optimize way for this situation where i can extract and delete the zip entry in chunks. there is no direct API's in minizip to delete, i am using raw write and read.

Thanks in advance,
JP

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to delete part of a file in a ZIP archive, short of extracting the whole file and archiving the part you don't want. (Which doesn't make sense here, since you're already trying to extract the file!)

Comment: I agree, my constraint was memory, so i didn't want to keep the zip archive till the extraction is over. for one file in archive there is no other option than to wait till the end of the extraction and delete the zip. Is there any other zip library which can help in achieving this?